# SELECT from an UNION ALL in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

When I do a :

```
SELECT id FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM table2
```

I get a new table with all the ids, and it's perfect.
But when I try a :

```
SELECT * FROM (
               SELECT id FROM table1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT id FROM table2
               )
```

It doesn't work, It doesn't return me anything.

May anyone help me ? I've tried a lot of things, and this is a very small code so I can't understand why it doesn't work.

Thank's a lot.

Comment: You forgot to alias the union result set.

Comment: What database are you using? Oracle would not require the alias. Most databses do require an alias for inline views

Comment: Yes, the alias is the answer, thank's a lot.

Comment: The query is working fine in oracle.

Comment: The OP clearly is using MSSQL and not Oracle. Had it been Oracle, it would have worked as is.

Answer (score 10):

You are missing the alias for the derived result set. Try the following

```
SELECT * FROM (
               SELECT id FROM table1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT id FROM table2
               ) as t
```

This would work with MSSQL, MySQL, however you would need to remove the "AS" when doing aliasing for Oracle.

Comment: Thank's a lot, the alias is the good way to do this.
And according to @paqomogez, the `t.`is optional. Thank you so much !

Comment: Glad I helped. Remember that if the answer solved your problem, make sure to mark it as answer.

Comment: it may be optional in some sql versions, but it's definitely not optional in mssql.

Answer (score 3):

http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2012/06/23/derived-table-aliases/

Different databases have different rules about giving an alias to an inline view or derived table (a subquery in the from clause)

Oracle would not have any problem with the query you posted.

MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL would. They require an alias.

What get's worse is using the AS keyword. Some databases are okay with it, others are not. If in the above query you used " as t" Oracle WOULD throw an error. The AS keyword is not required in any database, but some databases will not accept it (so universally speaking, it is best not to use AS in the FROM clause with actual tables or inline views).

The safest solution is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (
               SELECT id FROM table1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT id FROM table2
               ) t
```

Because it will work in any database. (notice that the AS keyword is not before t)